# Polars: Parsing nested fields when reading a csv file

Tags: python-polars

I have the following csv structure:

```
Some;Csv;Data;Nested|Field|Containing|An|Array;And;Some;More;Fields;Here
```

Is there any away to parse the nested list using polars ?

What is the expected output ?

```py
{
   "column_1": "Some",
   "column_2": "Csv",
   "column_3": "Data",
   "column_4": [
       "Nested",
       "Field",
       "Containing",
       "An",
       "Array"
   ],
   "column_5": "And",
   "column_6": "Some",
   "column_7": "More",
   "column_8": "Fields",
   "column_9": "Here"
}
```

I'm trying to parse the csv file using something like:

```py
pl.read_csv(
 source="somefile.csv",
 has_header=False,
 separator=";"
)
```

In the documentation they mention the `List` type, but I don't understood how to use it in the dtypes parameter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could [`.str.split`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.split.html#polars.Expr.str.split) the column after reading:

```
csv = b"""
Some;Csv;Data;Nested|Field|Containing|An|Array;And;Some;More;Fields;Here
""".strip()

(pl.read_csv(csv, separator=";", has_header=False)
   .with_columns(pl.col("column_4").str.split("|")))
```

```
shape: (1, 9)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬────────────────────────────────┬───┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ column_1 ┆ column_2 ┆ column_3 ┆ column_4                       ┆ … ┆ column_6 ┆ column_7 ┆ column_8 ┆ column_9 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---                            ┆   ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str      ┆ str      ┆ str      ┆ list[str]                      ┆   ┆ str      ┆ str      ┆ str      ┆ str      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪════════════════════════════════╪═══╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ Some     ┆ Csv      ┆ Data     ┆ ["Nested", "Field", … "Array"] ┆ … ┆ Some     ┆ More     ┆ Fields   ┆ Here     │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴────────────────────────────────┴───┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```